# MySQL get rows starting with specific id after sort / order by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I got this table:

```
id | score
1  | 1
2  | 4
3  | 4
4  | 3
5  | 2
6  | 2
7  | 1
8  | 4
9  | 2
10 | 3
```

I need to order it by score desc:

```
id | score
2  | 4
3  | 4
8  | 4
4  | 3
10 | 3
5  | 2
6  | 2
9  | 2
1  | 1
7  | 1
```

and get first 3 rows which starts with `id` `6`

So the result should be:

```
6  | 2
9  | 2
1  | 1
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
select t.*
from tablename t cross join (select * from tablename where id = 6) c
where t.score < c.score or (t.score = c.score and t.id >= c.id)
order by t.score desc, t.id
limit 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/34XJL9L48heXqRePfgrE4J/3).
Results:

```
| id  | score |
| --- | ----- |
| 6   | 2     |
| 9   | 2     |
| 1   | 1     |
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution

Comment: @EduardUnruh check an edited version of the code where you must specify `6` only once.

Comment: Nice! But I have one more question: is there a way I can sort it score desc, id desc before getting 3 rows starting with id 6? I tried by adding "desc" after t.id and get id 9,6,7 but it should be 6,5,7

Comment: If I understand this will do: `select t.*
from tablename t cross join (select * from tablename where id = 6) c
where t.score < c.score or (t.score = c.score and t.id <= c.id)
order by t.score desc, t.id desc
limit 3`

Comment: Perfect thanks again!! The hours of thinking how to solve my requirements by adding tons of unnecessary code before and after queries are over :D

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this with a cumulative `sum()` (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select 
    id, 
    score
from mytable
order by 
    sum(id = 6) over(order by score desc, id) desc, 
    score desc,
    id
limit 3
```

The `sum()` orders record in the required direction; as soon as the record that has `id = 6` is met, the sum takes value `1`. It allows to put these records on top. The rest is just adding the additional sorting criteria and limiting the number of results.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7F5B7HW8ZcjRZAUkRigTZ/0)**:

```
| id  | score |
| --- | ----- |
| 6   | 2     |
| 9   | 2     |
| 1   | 1     |
```

---

In earlier versions of mysql, you can emulate the window sum with a user variable, as follows:

```
select 
    id, 
    score
from 
  (select @sm := 0) s
  cross join (select id, score from mytable order by score desc, id) t
order by 
    case when id = 6 then @sm := @sm + 1 end desc, 
    score desc,
    id
limit 3
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7F5B7HW8ZcjRZAUkRigTZ/1)**: same results

Comment: I like your first solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: much appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: The first version will have to traverse through all records before id=6, and no index can help it, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

With this table

```
CREATE TABLE table3
    (`id` int, `score` int)
;

INSERT INTO table3
    (`id`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 2),
    (6, 2),
    (7, 1),
    (8, 4),
    (9, 2),
    (10, 3)
;
```

And this select

```
SELECT `id`, `score`
FROM (SELECT `id`,`score`,if (id = 8,@scoreid:= @scoreid +1,@scoreid) scoreid
       From table3, (SELECT @scoreid :=0) s  Order by score desc) t1 
Where scoreid > 0 LIMIT 3;
```

you get

```
id  score
8   4
4   3
10  3
```

DBFiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=95e2051d560c2ac27fdcc8f9d04acf5d

Comment: I had to uncheck it, it's not working when I try to get 5 rows starting with id 8, but @forpas solution works